# Apache Ignite : set remote filter factory on continuous query

Tags: java, ignite

Good morning guys,

I need to know if anyone can explain me how exactly work the remote filter on continuous query.

Can i define a HashSet in order to filter the cache Key? Can someone provide me a good example for clarify my doubts?
This is my code that does not work, where Filter is a HashSet. I think that the server node after the execution is in deadlock.

```
          qry.setRemoteFilterFactory(new Factory<CacheEntryEventFilter<String, JSONObject>>() {
                @Override public CacheEntryEventFilter<String, JSONObject> create() {
                    return new CacheEntryEventFilter<String, JSONObject>() {
                        @Override public boolean evaluate(CacheEntryEvent<? extends String, ? extends JSONObject> e) {

                            return Filter.contains(e.getKey());
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear where you take the map from, and what is actually not working. Keep in mind that the filter is called on server nodes, so this map has to be properly serialized and sent to all nodes.

In general, filter is based on key-value pair and usually it's stateless (for example, notify only about updates for events with a specific status). Having a map like this is likely to be too large on large datasets.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I missed to change in server mode the node. Now it works!!!